# Sonata admin User

Tags: symfony, permissions, sonata

I want to set up my own Permission in Sonata Admin Bundle but I read the documentation and I am confused. I can add the standard permission to roles but What I want to do is create my own permission "PUSH" that means if a user can create PUSH notification.

I am following the instructions given in [Official Documentation](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/security.html) but I am not able to do it. For sure that I am misunderstanding something because I think that is something really normal to do.

More in detail. We have these permissions and I want to add another permission here.

```
Permission  Description
LIST    view the list of objects
VIEW    view the detail of one object
CREATE  create a new object
EDIT    update an existing object
DELETE  delete an existing object
EXPORT  (for the native Sonata export links)
ALL grants LIST, VIEW, CREATE, EDIT, DELETE and EXPORT
```

My configuration is:

```
security:
    handler: sonata.admin.security.handler.acl

    information:
        PUSH:     [LIST, PUSH]
        GUEST:    [VIEW, LIST]
        STAFF:    [EDIT, LIST, CREATE, PUSH]
        EDITOR:   [OPERATOR, EXPORT]
        ADMIN:    [MASTER]

    admin_permissions: [VIEW, CREATE, LIST, DELETE, UNDELETE, PUSH, EXPORT, OPERATOR, MASTER]
```

But when I execute this command to setup the new command is not working

```
php app/console sonata:admin:setup-acl
```

I get this error:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
  The code "PUSH" is not supported
```

Any Ideas? Maybe is not possible to do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't find how to solve it what I want but I did a work around.

The Idea is that I create a new Role (PUSH_ROLE) and then I assigned this Role to the users that I want. Then in the twig template I check if is_granted('ROLE_PUSH') is True.

How to create a New role:

```
sonata_admin:
    security:
        handler: sonata.admin.security.handler.acl

        role_admin: ROLE_ADMIN
        role_super_admin: ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN
```